# Delete files extracted with xorriso

Tags: delete-file

I was looking for a way to extract an iso file without root access.
I succeeded using xorriso.
I used this command:
xorriso -osirrox on -indev image.iso -extract / extracted_path

Now when I want to delete the extracted files I get a permission denied error.
lsattr lists -------------e-- for all files.
ls -l lists -r-xr-xr-x for all files.

I tried chmod go+w on a test file but still can't delete it.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

obviously your files were marked read-only in the ISO. xorriso preserves
the permissions when extracting files.

The reason why you cannot remove the test file after chmod +w is that 
the directory which holds that file is still read-only. (Anyways, your
chmod command did not give w-permission to the owner of the file.)

Try this tree changing command:

```
chmod -R u+w extracted_path
```

Have a nice day :)

Thomas